# How to modify wordpress plugin css

Tags: css, wordpress

Please check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/Raakh5/hg6au2y2/

```
<div id="aq-block-1076-2" class="aq-block aq-block-aq_text_block aq_span4 aq-first clearfix">
<div class="cp-calc-widget" data-calcid="2424" data-anchor="2">
    <form class="widgetForm cleanslate" id="widgetForm" method="post" 
        style="width: 260px !important; background-color: #378CAF !important; 
        border-color: #006395 !important; color: #ffffff !important; font-size: 16px !important;">           

            <input name="numFields" type="hidden" value="1">           
            <input name="calcId" type="hidden" value="2424">
            <input name="answer_format" type="hidden" value="function">

            <div class="widgetTitle">Water Intake Calculator</div>           
            <hr style="color: #006395 !important; background-color: #006395 !important;">           
            <div class="form_area"><div class="field">Weight:<div class="buffer">
                <input class="inputArea" name="input0" value="">
            </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" id="widgetSubmit" class="widgetSubmit calc_button" value="Calculate" 
            style="color: #ffffff !important; background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #378CAF, #006395) !important; 
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #378CAF),color-stop(1, #006395)) !important; 
            filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=#378CAF, endColorStr=#006395, GradientType=0 ); 
            border-color: #006395 !important;">           
            </div>           

            <div class="answer_area hidden_class">             
            <div class="loading">loading...</div>             
            <div class="actual_answer hidden_class">               
            <span class="pre_answer"></span>               
            <div class="answer">
                <span class="return_answer"></span></div>             
            </div>             
            <div>
                <input type="button" id="backButton" class="backButton calc_button" value="< back" 
                style="color: #ffffff !important; background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #378CAF, #006395) !important; 
                background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #378CAF),color-stop(1, #006395)) !important; 
                filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=#378CAF, endColorStr=#006395, GradientType=0 ); 
                border-color: #006395 !important;">
            </div>           
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I have embedded wordpress plugin pro-calculator and want to change its:

1. Background Color
2. Button Color
3. Want to write lbs in Front of "Weight" as "Weight (lbs)"

Please advise

Comment: The plugin outputs all of the styles directly on the html elements themselves?? Ouch

Comment: @Chizzle can I change it in their php files or css files?

Comment: You can, but I wouldn't do that. An answer upcoming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I guess I found out a way, which is possible but a hack. Since `id`s are all same and you do use jQuery, it is easy to change it using `.css()`. Give this a try, which you are supposed to put in the CSS:

```
(function ($) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $(function () {
      $("#widgetForm").css({
        "border-width": "2px",
        "background-color": "#ccc",
        "border-color": "#99f"
      });
    });
  }, 1250);
})(jQuery);
```

Also, let's give a simple `setTimeout()` so that it takes the time to load the plugin. `:)`

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/2fqk93av/**

Comment: I tried this, but it says, `$` is undefined. Can you help?

Comment: @LifeSaver I am definitely sure that jQuery is there in your page. Lemme check.

Comment: @LifeSaver Ahh!!! I found out the issue, it is because jQuery doesn't use `$`, instead it uses `jQuery`! Okay, lemme update my answer and tell me if it works.

Comment: @LifeSaver I have also added the `setTimeout`. So let's see. This should work! `:)`

Comment: wow. great it worked but I want to change the button color as well. Please advise

Comment: @LifeSaver Use `$("#widgetSubmit").css({ ... });` for button! `:)`

Comment: Its worked fine. thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options.

**1) (Recommended)** Use a different plugin that doesn't put inline styles directly on html elements. Then you can style it with CSS and not have to battle inline styling.

**2)** Override the output of their display function. If they are using actions/hooks you should be able to de-register their function that displays the html on the page, copy it into your own function, and register your function in place of theirs. This would be nice becasue you could change output such as adding (lbs) to the weight input. [Here is an example of doing the action overrides.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201266/what-is-add-action-init/21201737#21201737)

The third and worst option is editing the plugin code directly but you **will lose all of your changes** if a site admin ever does the one-click plugin update in the wp-admin. This is obviously a unwanted scenario.

Comment: how can I know in which file author is written inline css code?

Comment: You'll have to dig through the author's source code. You should really just try to use a better plugin though if you have the ability to change plugins for the site.

Comment: `If they are using actions/hooks you should be able to de-register their function that displays the html on the page` can you please explain more about your aforementioned statement

Comment: There is a link in the answer in that section I talk about. You will need to look at the plugin source code and see if the function they are calling to display the output is registered with wordpress. If it is using action/hooks you could deregister their function call and replace it with your own. You basically would copy their source code and customize it in your functions.php file.

Comment: Can you please write an example specifically in my case?